# How to get the EntityManager inside of webtestcases in Symfony2

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

I was wondering how I could retrieve the entitymanager inside of a
WebTestCase instance.

e.g. to look whether a entity was really created in DB during the testrun.

Any ideas on that ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can retrieve the DIC (Dependency Injection Container) through the Kernel, which is a protected member of the WebTestCase.

You could do this from within your WebTestCase:

```
$em = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

**Update**

From your own comment, there is even a shortcut for this (since you will have a client anyway):

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
```

As is [mentioned in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#accessing-the-container).

Comment: thanks. realised yesterday that this by now is already documented: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#accessing-the-container

Comment: Ah great, there's even a shortcut. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you have your `client`, you can get the *Entity Manager* from it:

```
$em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Don't use `getEntityManager, it is deprecated since Symfony 2.1.

enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed and I'd like to add an update valid for Symfony 4.

If you need to access services in your tests you still need to get the container first. This can be done like:

```
$container = self::$container;
```

Now you can get a service, in this example the *entity manager*:

```
$this->em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

I use `$this` assuming the statement is written in the `setUp` method and needed in other test methods.

The relevant [section](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#accessing-the-container) of the official Symfony documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Comment: there is no container in WebTestCase